# Verifying a specific response value from Postman result

Tags: postman, response, verify

Is there any way to validate whether a specific value is returned within the entire response which we get from Postman tool and set pass/fail conditions. for eg., my URL will be like https://www.testdomain.com/login?memid=123 and the specific value I am expecting in the response should be containing 'value1', 'value2', 'value3' and if anything else returned for that parameter then it should fail. I tried console.log but it obviously only prints the value and I need to validate manually to check the pass / fail conditions. Thanks in advance.

Sample Response:
[image]

Comment: Can you update the question with an example of the response body please?

Comment: Here I am trying to find only members with Masters in Education Category (or a set of predefined education values) if I get any Bachelors or other qualifications which are not listed in my array then the test should fail.

Comment: Can add that to the question, rather than in the comments. There is an `edit` button under the `tags`.

Comment: Thanks Danny I was searching for it :)

Comment: That's not a valid JSON response so I'm not sure it that's the exact response or not. You can use the `Tests` in Postman to create a check for a value in the response. There is a pre-made `snippet` to help you with this but it would need to be amended to point at the `key` that you need to check. What is the value you need to check? Is it the same each time for a Masters?

Comment: I may change the education from Masters to Bachelors or any other value so I want to have those values in an array. Sorry for the formatting of the JSON response, the data was huge so I cut paste the part where I concentrate.